# Format of product_code is String and want to compare with a numeric value

Tags: mysql, sql

How to check if product_code is less than 1000 as it is in String format.
Format of product code - S10_2016

Comment: Can you explain what the nodes of the product code mean.

Comment: What is the product_code string value part which must be compared with 1000 as a number?

Answer (score 0):

try it ,its work fine..

```
 SELECT * FROM table_name where replace(replace(product_code, 'S', ''), '_', '') * 1.0 < 1000;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the cast function

CAST(value AS datatype)

Comment: `SELECT CAST('S10_2016' AS UNSIGNED INTEGER);` will return 0 (zero)